# Get only the children of a clicked div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm building this webpage and I have some photos for slideshow inside divs that open up a modal. I want to get all children of clicked div (myModal). I want to get all divs with class "mySlides" who are the children of a click div with class "myModal". This is my code:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
     showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
     showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
     var i;
     var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
     console.log(slides);
     var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot1");
     if (n > 3) {
      slideIndex = 1;
     }
     if (n < 1) {
      slideIndex = slides.length;
     }
     for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
     }
     for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active1", "");
     }
     slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
     dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active1";
    }
```

```html
<!-- reference item -->
    <div class="grid-item set-bg osobj" data-setbg="img/portfolio/2.jpg">
     <a class="myBtn" onclick="getSlides()"></a>
     <div class="myModal modal1">

      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal1-content">
        <span class="close1">&times;</span>
        <h2>smth</h2>
        <div class="post1-container">
       <div class="post1-thumb">

        <div class="slideshow1-container">
         <div class="mySlides">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
          <img src="img/portfolio/3.jpg" style="width: 550px; height: 450px;">
          <div class="text1">Opis slike1</div>
         </div>
         
         <div class="mySlides">
          <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
          <img src="img/portfolio/4.jpg" style="width: 550px; height: 450px;">
          <div class="text1">Opis Slike2</div>
         </div>
         
         <div class="mySlides">
          <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
          <img src="img/portfolio/6.jpg" style="width: 550px; height: 450px;">
          <div class="text1">Opis Slike3</div>
         </div>
         
         <button class="prev1" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</button>
         <button class="next1" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</button>
         
         </div>
         <br>
         
         <div style="text-align:center">
          <span class="dot1" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
          <span class="dot1" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
          <span class="dot1" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
         </div> 
       </div>
       </div>
      </div>
       
       </div>
    </div>
```

I tried using $(this).children but no luck like that:

```
function getSlides() {
    var slides1 = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
    console.log(slides1);
}
```

How can I achieve this? I have multiple reference items in my page all with different 3 images to show on modal open. But I want to select only those that are children to the clicked element (as now it returns me all "mySlides" divs).

Comment: The problem is that getSlides do not have `$(this)`. I need to know how/where you call `getSlides()`

Comment: @Roy oh, I forgot, I have it in <a class="myBtn" onclick="getSlides()"></a>

Comment: want to get all divs with class "mySlides"???

Comment: @Sushil yes, but only all divs with class "mySlides" of a clicked reference item.

Comment: @user3029612 you want to get get it on `<a class="myBtn" onclick="getSlides()"></a>` this button click???

Comment: `<a class="myBtn" onclick="getSlides()"></a>` you need a reference here. If getSlider() is ejecuted, we need to know which is the reference to looking for these slides... like `getSlides('myModal')`... and use `$('.'+varMyModal+' .mySlides').children('img').attr('src');`

Comment: @Roy myModal is child to myBtn. Also I tried that and it didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `onclick="getSlides()"` from DOM and Use this Jquery

```
$('.myBtn').off().on('click',function(){
$(this).next('.myModal').find('.mySlides').each(function(i,v){
    console.log($(v)[0].outerHTML);
   });
});
```

Comment: This works! Can you tell me how can I create a html collection out of this? I need $(v)[0] to be a html collection :D

Comment: @user3029612 $(v) is a collection of each `<div class="mySlides">` if you need HTML Collection of all  `<div class="mySlides">` you can use `$(this).next('.myModal')` only

Comment: no, I would like to create HTMLCollection of just those items inside $(v)

Comment: $(v) itself is a HTML Collection Object. Can you please elaborate what do you want to perform, it would be easier to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Look at this.** You have to pass `getSlides(var)` a new variable `postContainer`. 
 In this case is: `<div class="post1-container">`

```
function getSlides(postContainer) {
    $('.'+postContainer+' .mySlides').each(function(){
       var slideSrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
       console.log(slideSrc);
    });  
}
```

## Lets start again:

**Using the self object to find the slides**

```
<a class="myBtn" onclick="getSlides($(this))"></a>
//Pass the object to the function

function getSlides(dis) {
    //Search from the object, the nexts .mySlides
    $(dis).next().find('.mySlides').each(function(){
       var slideSrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
       console.log(slideSrc);
    });  
}
```

Comment: I understand this, but what do I pass in HTML via onclick="getSlides('whatdoIinserthere') ? If I do it like that onclick="getSlides(myModal') it returns me all the images...

Comment: That's becouse all you modal has the class myModal, use id's instead

Comment: I can't use ID's as I don't know how many reference items will there be and each would require a unique one

Comment: but all the modals has a class colled myModal?